# What is meaning of colon in Nisekoi second season name?

Tags: anime-production, nisekoi

Nisekoi second season has a ":" in the name like "Nisekoi:". What is the meaning of that colon?

Comment: there must literally be “nothing” to say about the show.

Comment: style I guess?? Just there to set it apart from the first season. Like SaeKano Flat.

Comment: Many anime has different symbols used in it e.g Steins;Gate, you can refer [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/13477/steinsgate-chaoshead-and-roboticsnotes-naming-convention-with-semicolon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's become something of a pattern that anime series will have some kind of notation to indicate sequel seasons. Obviously "Season 2" or variations thereof happen a lot (e.g. "Shokugeki no Soma The Second Plate"), but several shows add a small extra detail to the title instead. Besides *Nisekoi:*, here are a few:

- *Working!!* became *Working'!!* became *Working!!!*
- *K-On!* became *K-On!!*
- *Gintama* became *Gintama'* became *Gintama°* became *Gintama.*