# English letters in anime titles

Tags: tropes

I've frequently noticed in anime seasons the title of a series or film will have an English letter at the end of the title (for example: Dragon Ball Z, Sailor Moon S)- what is the significance of the letter?

Answer (score 4):

At least in the examples you've given, the letter helps differentiate a sequel show, or later season, from the original.

For example, the original *Dragon Ball* was followed by *Dragon Ball Z*, then *Dragon Ball GT*, then it gets complicated but they remade Z in a condensed form as *Dragon Ball Z Kai* and now there's *Dragon Ball Super*.

For *Sailor Moon*, the seasons after the first were *Sailor Moon R*, *Sailor Moon S*, *Sailor Moon SuperS* and *Sailor Stars*.

It's related to the practice of adding punctuation marks to a show's name to indicate later seasons, as discussed [in this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46338/what-is-meaning-of-colon-in-nisekoi-second-season-name/46364#46364) with examples like *Working!!* to *Working'!!* to *Working!!!*.